Inverse probability and Bayes' postulate according to Fisher
My two questions are simple and do not seek to engage the debate over inverse probability. In his 1925 Handbook, Fisher discusses the history of the subject and when speaking of Bayes he remarks: "We do know that the reason for his hesitation to publish was his dissatisfaction with the postulate required for the celebrated [result]".
First, what is the postulate that Fisher speaks of? Second, do we know, as he claims, the reason for Bayes' decision not to publish the paper? All the sources I have read are are coy on the subject. Did Bayes actually address this?

I don't remember, but perhaps this is found in the biography: A.I. Dale, Most Honourable Remembrance: The Life & Work of Thomas Bayes

Thanks, I'll check it out.

Indeed,, I think you gave me the answer to the first of my questions. In the opening paragraph Dale notes that Bayes assumed a uniform distribution for the value of the underlying parameter. Assuming that the parameter could be assigned any distribution would have been anathema to Fisher (and many others). I'll read on to see if Bayes remarked on the assumption, which would answer my second question.

Correction, in the opening paragraph of the review.
